# PHP Simple XML access a image url element value

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I'm writing a PHP script to fetch rss new feed and show, using php `simplexml_load_file` i managed to show most of contents of feed,

but stuck with accessing image link.

My code is here

```
      $url = "https://www.nu.nl/rss/Algemeen";       
             $feeds = simplexml_load_file($url);
             foreach ($feeds->channel->item as $item) {

                        $title = $item->title;
                        $link = $item->link;
                        $description = $item->description;
                        $postDate = $item->pubDate;
//to get the image

$imageurl = $item->enclosure->url;

    //example output

    echo "<h3 class='rstitle'>$title</h3><div class='rscont'>$description<div>";

        }
```

But the image attribute inside another level

sample part of xml var_dump

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["version"]=>
    string(3) "2.0"
  }
  ["channel"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (8) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "NU - Algemeen"
    ["link"]=>
    string(26) "https://www.nu.nl/algemeen"
    ["description"]=>
    string(37) "Het laatste nieuws het eerst op NU.nl"
    ["language"]=>
    string(5) "nl-nl"
    ["copyright"]=>
    string(22) "Copyright (c) 2019, NU"
    ["lastBuildDate"]=>
    string(31) "Wed, 06 Feb 2019 10:41:00 +0100"
    ["ttl"]=>
    string(2) "60"
    ["item"]=>
    array(10) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (7) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(74) "747.000 Nederlanders in laatste vijf jaar slachtoffer van huiselijk geweld"
        ["link"]=>
        string(115) "https://www.nu.nl/binnenland/5726055/747000-nederlanders-in-laatste-vijf-jaar-slachtoffer-van-huiselijk-geweld.html"
        ["description"]=>
        string(216) "In totaal 747.000 volwassen Nederlanders zijn in de afgelopen vijf jaar minstens één keer slachtoffer geweest van huiselijk geweld. Daarnaast krijgen jaarlijks 90.000 tot 127.000 kinderen te maken met mishandeling."
        ["pubDate"]=>
        string(31) "Wed, 06 Feb 2019 10:21:36 +0100"
        ["guid"]=>
        string(28) "https://www.nu.nl/-/5726055/"
        ["enclosure"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["url"]=>
            string(123) "https://media.nu.nl/m/m1nx2k0a3l3q_sqr256.jpg/747000-nederlanders-in-laatste-vijf-jaar-slachtoffer-van-huiselijk-geweld.jpg"
            ["length"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["type"]=>
            string(10) "image/jpeg"
          }
        }
        ["category"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "Algemeen"
          [1]=>
          string(10) "Binnenland"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (7) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(68) "FvD en DENK willen in alle provincies meedoen aan Statenverkiezingen"
        ["link"]=>
        string(108) "https://www.nu.nl/algemeen/5726574/fvd-en-denk-willen-in-alle-provincies-meedoen-aan-statenverkiezingen.html"
        ["description"]=>
        string(206) "Forum voor Democratie (FvD) en DENK willen in alle twaalf provincies meedoen aan de Provinciale Statenverkiezingen op 20 maart. De Kiesraad heeft woensdag bekendgemaakt welke partijen zich hebben aangemeld."
        ["pubDate"]=>
        string(31) "Wed, 06 Feb 2019 10:41:00 +0100"
        ["guid"]=>
        string(28) "https://www.nu.nl/-/5726574/"
        ["enclosure"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["url"]=>
            string(118) "https://media.nu.nl/m/k82xoojacd24_sqr256.jpg/fvd-en-denk-willen-in-alle-provincies-meedoen-aan-statenverkiezingen.jpg"
            ["length"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["type"]=>
            string(10) "image/jpeg"
          }
        }
        ["category"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "Algemeen"
          [1]=>
          string(8) "Politiek"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
```

I tried to access image url by   `$item->enclosure->url;` but it returns empty array

can anyone help me to get the image url, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$item->enclosure['url']
```

:)

Attributes are accessed by array accessor

You can also try xpath

```
$item->xpath('enclosure/@url')[0]
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my hours :)